# IntelliSense low speed in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have a solution with 4 projects, this projects have many css files. (about 50 large css files).
In html editor, when i write class="" it takes a long time to open list (about 10 seconds), after first word, it happens again.

Typing

```
class="btn btn-success btn-lg mybuttonclass"
```

take 40 seconds.
I installed web essential, it is not resolved.
I installed VS2013 Update 4 , it is not resolved.

I disabled IntelliSense for for HTML Editor in option menu, but i need it.

Comment: I suffer the same issues with solutions which contain more than 4-5 projects.

Comment: Did you find any answer?